# Missing UTF-8 charset in MAMP MySql

Tags: mysql, mamp

I am trying to run a MySql database with MAMP, but when I try to access the database, this error appears:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2019] Can't initialize character set UTF-8 (path: /Applications/MAMP/Library/share/charsets/)

I ran "show variables" and found that the charset is set to UTF-8. I also looked in the path mentioned in the error and found that there was no file that said anything about UTF-8, so it appears that this charset is missing. Huh??? If it's looking for this charset, it must usually be present. So why is the charset missing? How can I get it there?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. In my case I mistyped UTF-8 for establishing the connection.
Try to connect with the charset "utf8" instead of "UTF-8".

Apart from that I also have no UTF-8 charset file in that folder so I guess it's not the real problem.

Comment: I checked and `utf8` is defined in `Index.xml`. Strangely I see `utf-8` defined as an alias in there, so unsure where the problem is coming from. In my case I changed `utf-8` -> `utf8` and things started working.